# Does the spin of an electron change when transferred from one atom to another?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, atomic-physics, atoms

Some atoms form bonds when they are given energy to create an excited state.From what I have learnt, every electron is assigned a specific  spin quantum number. What I am curious to know,is that, is there a certain rule which restricts itself to the pairing of only opposite spinning electrons,or does an electron on transfer, during bond formation, change it's spin direction,and thus it's spin quantum number? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please look up *Pauli Exclusion Principle*.

Comment: Yeah I have looked up pauli's principle. What I meant to ask was whether spin of an electron will change when it is transferred from one atom to another

Comment: The spin of the electron can change as long as angular momentum conservation is not violated. If a photon leaves carrying 1+ then an electron can flip spin.

Comment: @anna That is correct but oversimplified. Spin-flip transitions are dipole-forbidden, and they can only happen via magnetic-dipole interactions, which means that they are generally very weak and happen very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

The spin of the electron can change
as long as angular momentum
conservation is not violated. If a
photon leaves carrying 1+ then an
electron can flip spin. – anna v

That is correct but
oversimplified. Spin-flip transitions
are dipole-forbidden, and they can
only happen via magnetic-dipole
interactions, which means that they
are generally very weak and happen
very rarely. – Emilio Pisanty